# " No such file or directory" when using Eigen3 in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, eigen

I downloaded the Eigen3 in [EIgen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and renamed the flie as "eigen3".
Then I added the path of "eigen3" to the additional include file path.
After that I added the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
void mian()
{

}
```

error arose like **can not open include file"Eigen/Dense",no such file or director**
That's strange since I use Eigen well in another project using PCL in which Eigen file is included.

Comment: Which file exactly did you download? You need to download an entire archive such as http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3.4.zip and extract that.

Comment: yes,I download the entire archive